# How to declare a vector of zeros in R

Tags: r

I suppose this is trivial, but I can't find how to declare a vector of zeros in R.

For example, in Matlab, I would write:

```
X = zeros(1,3);
```

Comment: rep(0, n) to repeat zero n times.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You have several options

```
integer(3)
numeric(3)
rep(0, 3)
rep(0L, 3)
```

Comment: I'd add also `seq(0,0,length.out=3)` or `as.vector(matrix(0,nrow=3))` :)

Comment: The solutions of @nicola are not efficient. `seq()` takes 4.6 times longer than `numeric`, `as.vector(matrix())` 3.5 times. `rep` takes 1.2 times longer.

Comment: @Thierry Yes, of course they are not. I was just joking and wanted to list "funny" ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: @nicola `exp(floor(seq(0, .9, length.out = 3))) - 1` is clearly superior

Answer (score 27):

You can also use the `matrix` command, to create a matrix with *n* lines and *m* columns, filled with zeros.

```
matrix(0, n, m)
```

Answer (score 14):

`replicate` is another option:

```
replicate(10, 0)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

replicate(5, 1)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

To create a matrix:

```
replicate( 5, numeric(3) )

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: syntax is really confusing .. please explain how matrix creation works

Comment: `replicate( 5, numeric(3) )` generates a matrix of size 3x5 filled with zeros. 
In general, `replicate( n, vec )`, outputs a matrix where the vector `vec` is repeated `n` times. Try e.g., `replicate(8, c(5,2,4,7))`

Answer (score 5):

```
X <- c(1:3)*0
```

Maybe this is not the most efficient way to initialize a vector to zero, but this requires to remember only the `c()` function, which is very frequently cited in tutorials as a usual way to declare a vector.

As as side-note: To someone learning her way into R from other languages, the multitude of functions to do same thing in R may be mindblowing, just as demonstrated by the previous answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Here are four ways to create a one-dimensional vector with zeros - then check if they are identical:

```
numeric(2) -> a; double(2) -> b; vector("double", 2) -> c; vector("numeric", 2) -> d
identical(a, b, c, d)
```

In the [iteration chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html) in R for Data Science they use the "d" option to create this type of vector.